# Angular Reactive Forms unable to get formControlName to set value on an ngFor template loop

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, ngfor

I am using Angular reactive forms and I am trying to get a form control value to set as default value on a drop-down list. I am able to get this to work if I do not use the *ngFor loop in my template code. However, I need to use this as I will have many options in the  tag.

```
    <select formControlName="staffName">
       <option>Bob Jason</option>
       <option>Sally Reel</option>
       <option>Jack Jones</option>  
       <option>George Smith</option>  
       <option>Harry Lake</option>  
    </select>
```

However, if I use the code below, it does not work

```
     <select formControlName="staffName">
        <option *ngFor="let StaffMemberModel of StaffMemberModels">
            {{StaffMemberModel.firstName}} {{StaffMemberModel.lastName}}
        </option>      
     </select>
```

The StaffMemberModel is an array of that that contains id, firstName, and lastName as shown below.

[image]

It outputs the below. However, it only shows the first option in the drop-down, when it should show the staff member that has been selected in the previous page.

[image]

Comment: see that you has NO a variable in your .ts called "StaffMemberModel". NOTE: In Angular usually (is recomendary, not mandatory) you use camelCase to give name to variables -so the variables allways begin by lowercase, better staffMemberModel than StaffMemberModel-, and the Class and interface by uppercase-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it so by passing the `[value]="StaffMemberModel.id"` flag.

*It can be firstName, lastName, ID, whatever you want.*

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <select formControlName="staffName">
    <option *ngFor="let StaffMemberModel of StaffMemberModels"
    [value]="StaffMemberModel.id" > 
      {{ StaffMemberModel.firstName }} {{ StaffMemberModel.lastName }}</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

If you want to see it in action:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w8bjyl